# How do I write a trigger to hash value before insert?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I have a table called `employees` with 3 columns: `FirstName`, `LastName`, and `SSN`.

Data is fed into this table nightly by a .Net service, something I'm not comfortable updating.

I'd like to have a trigger that says:

> Hey, I see you're trying to insert something in the SSN column... let's HASH that before it goes in.

Answer (score 5):

One way is to use an INSTEAD OF TRIGGER:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.HashSSN
ON dbo.tablename
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  INSERT dbo.tablename(FirstName, LastName, SSN)
    SELECT FirstName, LastName, HASHBYTES('SHA1', SSN)
    FROM inserted;
END
GO
```

Answer (score 3):

### Business Rule Compliance and Staging Tables

Another way is to not insert to the final table but to use a staging table. The staging table is a sort of permanent temporary table that has no constraints, allows `NULL`s, is in a schema such as `import` and is simply a container for an external data source to drop data into. The concept is then that a business process with proper business logic can be set up to operate on the data in the container.

This is a kind of "data scrubbing" layer where the SSN hashing could be done, as well as other business processes operating or business rules being enforced such as nullability or allowed omissions, capitalization, lengths, naming, duplicate elimination, key lookup, change notification, etc, and then finally performing the insert. The benefit is that a set of bad data, instead of having been attempted to insert, being forced to roll back, and then blowing up the original process, can be detected, preserved intact without loss and ultimately be properly handled (such as being moved to an error queue, notifications sent, and so on).

Many people would use SSIS for tasks like this, though I personally find SSIS very hard to work with, since it has problems ranging from brittleness, difficulty using SPs containing temp tables, deployment challenges, not being part of database backups, and others.

If such a scheme seems like overkill to you so that you wouldn't even consider it, step back for a second and think about it: you have an external process that is supposed to be inserting proper, exact, scrubbed, and certainly-known data into a table. But, it's not doing that. Instead, it's inserting data that does not conform to business rules. I think that slapping on a trigger could be a way to handle it, but this is also an opportunity for you to think more about the architecture of the system and explore why you're having this problem in the first place.

How do you think untrusted or non-business-rule-compliant data should be become trusted and business-rule-compliant? Where do transformation tasks such as hashing an SSN column belong?

Should the inserting process be aware of such business rules? If so, is this consistent across the organization, the architecture, the type of process that inserter is? If not, how will you address this so going forward you're not putting patches on fixes on kluges?

### The Insecurity of an SSN Hash

Furthermore, I would like to point something else out. There are only about 889 million SSNs possible (888,931,098) if there are no TINs. How long do you think it would take to run through all of them and compare the hash to those in your table? Hashing certainly reduces quick exposure--you can't just read the SSN out extremely easily. But given it only takes a billion tries, it's a matter of days or even hours to pop all of them, depending on resources and planning.

A rainbow table with all SSNs and their SHA1 hashes would only take on the order of 25-30 GB -- quite achievable even on a relatively inexpensive home computer, where once created it would allow popping any SSN in a split second. Even using a longer or more computationally expensive hash isn't going to help much. In a matter of days or weeks a rainbow table can be built. A few hundred bucks can buy multiple terabytes of storage nowadays.

You could salt the SSN hash, which will mean that if someone runs a brute force crack against your table they will have to do it once for each row rather than be able to get all the rows at once. This is certainly better, but it only delays the inevitable. A serious hacker probably has a bot army backing him up that can crack a simple SSN + salt in a matter of seconds.

### Further Thoughts

I would be interested in the business rules that are on the one hand requiring you to be able to verify SSNs and use them as a type of password, but on the other hand not allowing you to store the full values. Do you have security concerns about your database? Now that you've updated your question to say that these are employees, my questions about why the exclusion of non-SSN-holders is moot. However, I'm still curious why you need to hash the values and can't just store them. It's not just fine but *required* for an employer to have its employees' SSNs so it can report earnings and deductions to the government.

If on the other hand, your concern isn't really about security but more about deniability ("your SSN is never stored on our servers!") then that isn't really true, now, is it? All you've done is transform it in a way that can be reversed through brute-force, and the search space is small enough that brute force is quite reasonable. If someone gives you the number 42, and you multiply it by 2 and save 84, then tell the person that his number was not stored, but you can simply divide 84 by 2 to get the original number, then you're not really being completely straightforward.

Certainly, "one-way" hashing is much harder to reverse than multiplying, but we're not dealing with a problem such as "find the original 200 thousand-character document (or whatever) from its hash" but "find a 9 digit number from its hash". Sure, many different inputs will hash to the same values as one particular SSN, but I doubt that there are very many collisions of exactly 9-character strings consisting exclusively of numeric digits.

### Actual SHA-1 SSN Hash Reversal Testing

I just did some testing. I have a table with about 3200 real SSNs in it. I hashed them using SHA1 and put those hashes into a temp table containing just the one column. I was able to pop 1% of the SSNs in about 8 minutes searching upward from `001-01-0001`. Based on the speed of processing and the total search space it will be done in less than 3 hours (it's taking ~2 minutes per 10 million SSNs, so 88.89 * 2 minutes). And this is from *inside* SQL Server, not running a compiled program that could be much, much faster. That's not very secure!

Comment: You can use PBKDF2, bcrypt or scrypt with a large random salt and a high number of iterations to make it a bit harder to get to the SSN's. That said, if you see SSN's as a very badly chosen password, in the end you are fighting a lost war. Encryption and a good set of separation between the various components of the system might be a better idea.